# Project Euler Q2 Python - Crashes Notebook

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve Project Euler's Question #2 in Python:

> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
>   exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

My solution seems to be crashing my Jupyter notebook even though it makes conceptual sense:

```
f = [1,2]        

for i in range(0,4000001):
    if (i%2 == 0):
        fibo_last = f[-1]+f[-2]
        f.append(fibo_last)
print sum(f)
```

I'm curious why my solution seems to work only for small values

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, you are not getting the value because the value is so big take a look of the output of Fibonacci for 400:

> 176023680645013966468226945392411250770384383304492191886725992896575345044216019675

I don't want to tell how to do it, if you look, there is a lot of way, if you insist, I can add a solution, but I think your question is **why?** and not **how to**. So You have to recreate your algorithm to be more efficient.

Comment: thanks, I just realized that I misunderstood the question. In my erroneous solution I'm trying to calculate the four millionth fibonacci number!

Comment: @abstract no problem, understand the problem and start to solve it, is 70% of the job (my old father says)